# SSL Handshake failure when using a TLSv1.3 ciphersuite on ApacheBench (ab)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, apache2, ab

I was trying to use the **Apache Bench (ab)** on my local server which is running **Apache HTTP Server**, with the **ssl** module enabled, using the **TLS1.3** as a protocol to use in communication but anytime I try to use it I have an **SSL handshake failure message** appearing on my command line terminal.

What I have done is simply installing **apache2** on my local PC (running Zorin OS 15.2) and made some changes in the **ssl.conf** file, which I specified the **SSL Protocols** to use:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

and in the site configuration file to activate the SSL Engine, specify all the certificate files, assigning the Server Name etc.

After all of this is done I simply run the command ab for testing and if I run the command like this:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 https://myhostname/
```

Everything works fine but if I try to specify the protocol TLS1.3, using one ciphers that is used for TLS1.3, it gives the following error message:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 -Z TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 https://myhostname:443/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking hostname (be patient)
SSL handshake failed (1).
139632751683456:error:141A90B5:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_list_to_bytes:no ciphers available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:3786:No ciphers enabled for max supported SSL/TLS version
```

What is strange to me is if I run the same command using some ciphers supported by TLS1.2 everything works fine but if I use any ciphers supported by TLS1.3 I get that error.

I even tried to do a simple connect using **openssl s_client** with the option -**tls1_3** for connecting to my server using TLS1.3 as a protocol and the connection works fine.

Here is a list of software I'm using:

- Apache HTTP Server (version 2.4.29)
- ApacheBench (version 2.3)
- OpenSSL (version 1.1.1)

What I want is simply running the same command but with the use of ciphers supported by the protocol TLS1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html#options) has:

> `-f` protocol
>
> Specify SSL/TLS protocol (SSL2, SSL3, TLS1, TLS1.1,
> TLS1.2, or ALL). TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 support available in 2.4.4 and
> later.

That's also mentioned in the [changelog](https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/CHANGES_2.4):

> Changes with Apache 2.4.4
>
> - `ab`: add TLS1.1/TLS1.2 options to `-f` switch, and adapt output to more accurately report the negotiated protocol. PR 53916. [NicolÃ¡s
>   Pernas Maradei , Kaspar Brand]

As there's no similar mention on TLS 1.3, one could assume `ab` doesn't support it yet (despite Apache 2.4 supports TLS 1.3).

Comment: Hi @EsaJokinen. Thanks for the reply. It doesn't matter the -f option because using -Z it tells to ab which protocol must use. Of course someone can use the -f option with -Z, like is suggested, and at the end the result is the same. The fact that ab doesn't support TLS 1.3 it could be true that's why I have searched online another tool called [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which is a more complex tool compared to ab but in the end it could give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

latest version supports TLS1.3 now

```
[root@5b2407a280df /]# ab -V
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1903618 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

[root@5b2407a280df /]# ab -h
Usage: ab [options] [http[s]://]hostname[:port]/path
Options are:
 ...
    -f protocol     Specify SSL/TLS protocol
                    (SSL2, TLS1, TLS1.1, TLS1.2, TLS1.3 or ALL)
 ...
```